# css animation is stretched out

Tags: css, css-animations

My circle animation looks stretched out? How can I make the circle not look elongated in the x axis? It stretches out during the animation and then returns back to normal after the animation has finished.

```css
p {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

.ball {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

.animation-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
    width: 300%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-container">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>

<div class="animation-container">
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You animate width, what else do you expect? Maybe try animating height too.

Comment: okay, I was confused because the tutorial I was following had included the width for the paragraph element, although I'm not exactly sure why. Removing it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are animating your `width` from 300% to 100%. Removing this will fix it.

```css
p {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

.ball {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

.animation-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-container">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>

<div class="animation-container">
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```